# Is it possible to skip multiple ChannelHandler's when writing?

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to skip multiple ChannelHandler's in my write pipeline in order to send a small debug ByteBuf. I understand you can just develop multiple paths in the same pipeline depending on the object, but for this I just want to quickly dump this ByteBuf at the very end of my pipeline. So for example:

Pipeline (Out):
Base -> Encoder -> Batcher -> Encrypter -> Frame length appender

So I want to go from Base, all the way to my Frame length appender.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but I would really not recommend it. It's much better to let your `ChannelHandler` do the right thing depending on the message type.

That said something like this would do it:

```
ChannelHandler context = channel.pipeline().context(Encrypter.class);
context.write(msg);
```

Comment: What's strange is, I tried this exact thing but it still doesn't bypass the other handlers in the pipeline. I ended up just making a tree pipeline, so debug messages have their own route. I don't like it, but it'll have to do for now.

Comment: that cant be true... if you call `context.write` it will start at this context. Maybe the ordering in your pipeline is not what you described or expected ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
ctx.pipeline().context("Encrypter").write("your msg");
```

this will get the Encrypter ChannelHandlerContext and fire the next Frame length appender handler to process.